# How to get full page content in continuous requests (in loop) to gumtree.com using Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape phone numbers from cars listing on gumtree.com. The problem is when I do 'get' request to gumtree.com, it returns the whole content (HTML+JavaScript) for 4,5 requests but after that, it only returns JavaScript.

Then I wait for 5 minutes and then I try again and it returns the whole content (HTML+JavaScript) for 4,5 requests and then again returns the only JavaScript. I am confused about why this is happening. They have not banned my IP. I can still send a request and the whole content (HTML+JavaScript) is returning but the problem is I am unable to get the whole content (HTML+JavaScript) for all requests.

This is the link https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=cars&search_location=ls14jj&distance=1000&seller_type=private that I am scraping, it contains the car list. I get all links of ads and then I iterate each link to get the phone number from each ad.

What I have tried?

1. I have tried HTML requests in Python https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/
2. I have used selenium with Chrome headless browser but the browser also shows an empty page after 4,5 requests
3. I have used the IP rotation trick but the problem is some IPs works and some not, also I think it is not an IP issue because I am still sending requests from the same IP I have even added sleep for 50 seconds.

Here is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from selenium import webdriver 
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import time 
session = HTMLSession()

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.gumtree.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4391.1 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'referer': 'https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=cars&search_location=ls14jj&distance=1000&seller_type=private',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'cookie': 'gt_ab=ln:MzhhaQ==; gt_p=id:OWYzY2I3Y2MtZTIxYS00OWQ1LWIzYjUtYzNhMDRiYjk4MDNi; gt_appBanner=',
}

s = requests.Session()

response = session.get('https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=cars&search_location=ls14jj&distance=1000&seller_type=private',headers=headers, timeout=(5, 27))


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')


ul = soup.find("ul", attrs={"class": "list-listing-maxi"})

lis = ul.findChildren("li",recursive=False)

for li in lis:

  ad = li.find("article", attrs={"class": "listing-maxi"})
  
  adLink = ad.find("a", attrs={"class": "listing-link"})
  adLink = adLink.get('href')
  if 'gumtree' in adLink:
    adLink = adLink
  else:
    adLink = adLink.replace("/p","https://www.gumtree.com/p")

  adID = ad.get('data-q')
 
  adID = adID.split('-')
  adID = adID[1]
  revealUrl = adLink
  response = session.get(revealUrl, timeout=(10, 27))
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
  f = open("abc.html", "wb")
  f.write(response.content)
  f.close()

  fone = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "seller-phone-reveal"})

  if fone is None:
    fone = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "space-mbs"})
  
  fone = fone.find("a")
  fone = fone.get('href')
  fone = fone.split('&')
  
  try:
    fone = fone[1]
  except IndexError:
    fone = soup.find("a", attrs={"id": "reply-panel-reveal-btn"})
    fone = fone.get('href')

  token = fone.replace("rt=","")
  print(token)
  print('-----------------')

  time.sleep(50)
```

It is not a login issue. The page is accessible without a login. Can Scrapy handle this issue?

Comment: try adding more sleep and you may also rotate ip after every sleep

Comment: @AbhinavKumar I have already added sleep for 50 seconds. It is more than enough.